# Share books and bookmarks between all devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, books, bookmarks

I have lots of books bought or downloaded not from Apple's store.

I would like to simply put a book on my mac, then see it on my iPhone and iPad.
I also like to read it on my iPad, set a **bookmark**, and keep reading from same page on my iPhone.

Why Apple makes it so hard to work natively with MY books ? 
Its my device, so why is it matter how did I get my book ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [iBooks with iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT205751) makes this very easy.

- Make sure you have an active iCloud account and are signed in on both macOS and iOS.
- Open iBooks (if asked enable iCloud for iBooks).
- Select File > Add to library, and add any external .epub or .pdf files
- iBooks will automatically sync them to other iOS/macOS devices, including notes and bookmarks.

If you have a seperate iCloud and AppStore Apple ID. Go into iBooks preferences and check "Sync: Sync bookmarks, highlights and collections across devices", you might get a warning to change Apple ID's. Change it to your AppStore Apple ID. Even though your using iCloud to sync, it still needs the other ID.

Comment: Thanks but obviously this is never ever works, for the past few years. The book is on the mac, same iCloud, a lot of paid space, and book never appears on iPhone or iPad. And vise versa. I am not even talking about bookmarks. It is just not working.

Comment: Double check your iCloud settings. System Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Drive > Options. Make sure iBooks.app is ticked.

Comment: If your still having trouble, I'd recommend isolating the issue by creating a new iCloud account and a new user on your Mac. Also try doing a software re-set on your iOS device.

Comment: thanks in the mac iCloud options iBooks was not ticked! I ticked it but its still not appear on my iphone. Is there a similar setting on the iPhone to make it work? how I make sure on the iPhone and iPad that the ibooks is setup with iCloud ?